# UITableView Inside a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

How can I set **multiple table** view data inside a **collectionView**?

Answer (score 3):

I think its too complex to add multiple table views inside one UICollectionViewCell. Embedded scroll views is not recommended in terms of UX.

But you can do it by subclassing The UICollectionViewCell and be the delegate/datasources of table views.

You can use only one table with multiple sections instead of multiple tables.

Comment: can I set one table in one collectionview cell

Comment: Yes you can but if the UICollectionView will be scrollable. So please make the table not scrollable Or vice verse, make the table is not scrollable if the collection is scrollable. Two scrolls are confusing for users.

Comment: Set tableView scroll vertical and collectionView scroll horizontal. But how to add tableView in collectionView Cell?

Comment: Just as a subview, if you're using storyboard, just drag the table and add it as a subview. Or if you create it via code, just create UITableview instance, set delegate/datasource and add it as a subview

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yHBftX9-0Binzm9Br48uK8IvbT66Ww2JX1rVTHvgkfo/edit?usp=sharing    .....Like This category switch to left-right direct on screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by giving ***tag*** to each `UITableView` in all the `UICollectionViewCells` and you have to manage all `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` methods by ***tags*** of particular tableView.

I know its complicated but you can try this out.

Comment: i can't help @saini because it will take lots of time to do this practically.

Comment: i hope you w'll understand.